# Inline images are not converting to amp in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I am using amp module with its respective themes and libraries in Drupal 8. Everything works fine other than the inline images and iframes are not converted to amp. I have enabled 'Power User: Run the whole HTML page through the AMP library' but those inline tags are removed. Is there any way to convert inline  tag to .